# Releasing updates to your android application

Tags: android, version, release, google-play

I put out an android app last week, and wanted to release an update to it that will include additional phrases to a specific aspect of the app.  It isn't a big release that serves as a bug fix (no known bugs actually - fingers crossed ;p) but it will certainly add to the entertainment value of the app and add a lot of flexibility.

Is this poor practice, as new releases should include a lot of content or is this accepted for the most part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO that's fine - in fact desirable.

Additional content is always welcome.

I use a Spanish Verbs app, and early on it had some important verbs missing, but I was glad when they came in soon after.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, We can release minor updates to the applicatio as well, it is always acceptable and desirable.

I have also released the minor updates to my one of the application, they were for the solving the bug and issues raised in the application.

So you can also do the same !!

But for that You need to Change the **`versionCode`** and **`versionName`** attributes inside the AndroidManifest.xml file for releasing a udpate version of the same application.

For example:

```
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.0.2"
```